# moving ArrayList values from one tab to another

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, actionlistener

i was given a project to do named DoctorsCare in which you have a login window and a window with 3 tabs( Booking, Doctors screen , register) the purpose of this program is so that patients can book appointments and let the doctor know their name, id and other information. the problem is i cant figure out how to move the arraylist values from the class BookingPage to the doctors screen tab.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class NextPage extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    NextPage()
    {
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane1 = new JTabbedPane();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();

        JTextArea txt = new JTextArea(10,20);
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();

        tabbedPane1.add("booking",panel1);
        tabbedPane1.add("Doctors Screen",panel2);
        tabbedPane1.add("Register",panel3);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(tabbedPane1);
        frame.setSize(600, 500);
        frame.setTitle("Welcome to DoctorsCare");

        frame.setVisible(true);

        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setLabel("Take Appointment");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160,40));
        panel1.add(button);

        JButton button2 = new JButton();
        button2.setLabel("Cancel Appointment");
        button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160,40));
        panel1.add(button2);
        button.addActionListener(this);
                 panel2.add(txt);

                 DoctorsScreen dscrn = new DoctorsScreen();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

            BookingPage page = new BookingPage();
        }   
        }




import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.Normalizer.Form;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;


public class BookingPage extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    //public static ArrayList<List<String>> model = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    JFrame frame1= new JFrame();
    JTextField id;
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Patient ID:");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Name:");
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Gender:");
    JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Date of Birth:");
    JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Address:");
    JLabel label7 = new JLabel("Phone:");
    JLabel label6= new JLabel("brief patient history:");
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JTextArea phistry = new JTextArea(11,31);
    JTextField text1 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField text2 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField text3 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField text4 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField text5 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField text6 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField text7 = new JTextField(20);
    JButton button = new JButton("SUBMIT");

    BookingPage()
    {
        frame1.setTitle("Booking Appointment");
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.setSize(600,400);
        frame1.add(panel1);
        panel1.add(label);

        panel1.add(text1);
        panel1.add(label2);
        panel1.add(text2);
        panel1.add(label3);
        panel1.add(text3);
        panel1.add(label4);
        panel1.add(text4);
        panel1.add(label5);
        panel1.add(text5);
        panel1.add(label7);
        panel1.add(text7);
        panel1.add(label6);
        panel1.add(phistry);
        panel1.add(button);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160,40));
        button.addActionListener(this);


    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {     

        PatientInfo info = new PatientInfo();
        info.setPName(text2.getText());
        info.setID(text1.getText());
        info.setGender(text3.getText());
        info.setDoB(text4.getText());
        info.setAddress(text5.getText());
        info.setphistry(text6.getText());

        info.pRefList.add(info);
```

DoctorsScreen dscrn = new DoctorsScreen();

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new PatientInfo().pRefList.get(0).getPName());
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new PatientInfo().pRefList.get(0).getID());
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new PatientInfo().pRefList.get(0).getGender());
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new PatientInfo().pRefList.get(0).getDoB());
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new PatientInfo().pRefList.get(0).getAddress());
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new PatientInfo().pRefList.get(0).getphistry());


    }
;}

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class PatientInfo {
        private String ID ;
        private String PName;
        private String Gender;
        private String DoB;
        private String Address;
        private String phistry;

        public static ArrayList<PatientInfo> pRefList = new ArrayList<>();

        public String getID()
        {
            return this.ID;
        }

        public String getPName()
        {
            return this.PName;
        }
        public String getGender()
        {
            return this.Gender;
        }
        public String getDoB()
        {
            return this.DoB;
        }
        public String getAddress()
        {
            return this.Address;
        }
        public String getphistry()
        {
            return this.phistry;
        }

        public void setID(String ID)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
        }
        public void setPName(String PName)
        {
            this.PName = PName;
        }
        public void setGender(String Gender)
        {
            this.Gender = Gender;
        }
        public void setDoB(String DoB)
        {
            this.DoB = DoB;
        }
        public void setAddress(String Address)
        {
            this.Address = Address;
        }
        public void setphistry(String phistry)
        {
            this.phistry = phistry;
        }

        public static int size(int size) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             size=7;
            return 0;
        }

}
```

Comment: Not sure about others, but I don't really understand what it is you're asking. Please consider explaining your current code in greater detail as well as your current problem, what you've done to try to solve your problem,... etc... otherwise about all I can recommend is that you strive for good MVC separation of concerns.

Comment: More than one view (tab) can listen to the same model (list).